# 16-segments LED still on while disabling "enable"

Tags: transistors, led

I've created my own "enable" of a 16-segments by transitioning the common pin using a transistor, but there's one pin (G2) that it's on even when enable is turned down.

You can see the 16-segments logic here:
[image: 16-segments]

ENxL are powered by an Arduino (that can output 0V or 3.3~5V).

Notice that G2 is always on, the rest is powered with "step-up" transistors (but this part does work, I just had to tune the resistor values):

[image: Rest of segments]

**Why is G2 on, even with enable down? Is there a way to fix it?**

Edit: The "L" digit does turn off when enable is down.

When I say "G2" and "L" I mean the G2 and L pins from the bottom segments (the ones that are connected to +5V). That is LED2, LED4, LED6 and LED8.

Comment: Because soldering? Bad connectors? Broken components? Wrong GPIO setup? There isn't enough info to point out the problem.

Comment: There are two "single LED" segments no grounded: G1 and G2. Strange they should not behave the same - in all of "Segment 1" to "Segment 4"?

Comment: @greybeard I don't know where you see this, but if you think "G" stands for "Ground" you're wrong, ground is "COM", and G1/G2 are more LEDs

Comment: @Lundin I'll check the soldering and components, but it's not a GPIO problem because **the L pin** (also always connected to +5V) **does turn off when enable is pulled down**

Comment: In your first schematic, a lot of segments are grounded, including in particular A1/2&D1/2. Have a look at the FJ15103AH datasheet for an idea why to call "the 1/2 segments" *single LED*.

Comment: Does your 16-seg datasheet give a spec for reverse leakage current through each segment? Since you have multiple segments in each display grounded & in parallel with each other, that reverse leakage current can add up and may be enough current to light up the G2 segment.

Comment: One idea to test [@brhans' hypothesis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666043/16-segments-led-still-on-while-disabling-enable?noredirect=1#comment1772974_666043) would be to *disconnect* G2, the 150 Ω resistor and +5 V: The L segment might lit - more dimly than G2 did? The datasheet shows a single \$V_F\$ which contradicts depicting 10 segments as 2 diodes in series.

Comment: (@brhans: <20 μA@25°C, 5 V)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your “Enable” leaves COM in high impedance. So when G2 and L are 5V, the reverse leakage of all the other unused diodes that are grounded provides a path for G2, L to ground. L turns off because it is two diodes in series. G2 remains lit because it is a single diode.

There are two solutions:

1. Greybeard’s answer
2. Modify your enable circuit to apply a low impedance 5V to COM when disabled.

Edit based on comment.

> I wasn't aware of this kind of witchery the LEDs were capable of... What resistor value would you recommend to use as a pull-up? 140k, or less?

Not witchery. All diodes have a reverse leakage. Definitely <140k. The resistor has to pass all the leakage current. Don't guess. Calculate.

A pullup resistor in COM will work. You can calculate this way. Lets assume worse case 1 led on, the 16 grounded

1. 20 micro-amps leakage per pin
2. 16 leaky pins
3. That means 320 micro-amps that will definitely make the one LED glow.
4. Choose voltage drop across the resistor, say 0.5V. You can experiment.
   $$R_{PUP}=\frac{0.5}{0.32}k\Omega\approx1.5k\Omega$$

Comment: I wasn't aware of this kind of witchery the LEDs were capable of... What resistor value would you recommend to use as a pull-up? 140k, or less?

Comment: It didn't work with 100k, nor 10k, but it did work with 1k pull-up. Isn't the value too low? Or it's just fine?

Comment: Se my edit. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The simple remedy would seem to not connect unused segments to GND, but to COM, if at all.